# Letter writing: Refering to enclosed items

Tags: letter-writing

I am writing a letter, in it I want to refer to other items enclosed within the letter, is there any proper way to do this?

As an example of what I mean, I was thinking something like:

> ... my id card (see item 1 enclosed) ...

And then having an item within the envelope labeled item 1

I feel like I have seen or heard of a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Maybe staple or paperclip your whole packet, label attached items with numbers only, and write "my ID card (attachment 1)" or "my ID card (attached, #1).

Comment: How many items are you enclosing; and is it reasonably clear which one is (for example) your ID card? You could simply refer to them as "enclosures" and, unless they're very similar indeed, rely on the person's ability to distinguish them. (It would be difficult, for example, to confuse most ID cards with most letters of reference or resumes.)

Comment: There will probably be 3 items, but two of them will be similar

Comment: I remember reading of one oldish way to put it: "Enclosed you will find.."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word `enclosure` can be used.  It not only means `something that encloses`, but also `something that is enclosed`.  Dictionary.com defines this as definitions 1 and 2 here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enclosure?s=t.

It is common in business communication to say something like, "Please see enclosure 2 for a copy of my address proof," or "Please see enclosed item 2 for a copy of my address proof."

Usually, such letters have an "Encl." section right after the closing signature.  For instance:

```
Dear Mr. Smith,

<body of your letter>

Yours truly,
Jane Doe

Encl.:
        1. Copy of Master's Degree award
        2. Copy of address proof
        3. Copy of Social Security Number allotment letter
```

Comment: This looks really good and I have used something like it, I am not sure how to award the answer tick though as this answer doesn't feel very definitive as a general answer for some reason, actually I guess I will award it to you as I can change it later if something better comes.

Comment: Glad to be of help, scjr.  I appreciate your thought and comment.

Comment: enclosures are not always numbered like that. A dash on each line is used.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, you would refer to the enclosed items in the body of your letter followed by (enclosed) and then, under the signature at the end of the letter you'd write "Enclosures (x)" where x is the number of enclosures.

So, you'd write:

> ...my ID card (enclosed).

and after the signature:

> Enclosures (3)

It's assumed the recipient will have the ability to differentiate between the various enclosures and only needs to know how many there ought to be (so they can check to make sure you enclosed them all).

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

Mostly, you expect the receiver to be able to differentiate the enclosed items. So, you only need to mention the enclosed documents.

You could say, "the following items are enclosed:". You could also say, "please find the enclosed items listed below:" and then list the items. For example,

Please find the following items enclosed:

- National identity card
- Electricity bill
- Two copies of my recent passport photograph
- Two reference letters

If you are writing an email, here is an article that explains the [guideline and provides templates for writing this kind of email](http://www.woculus.com/communicate-email-attachments/).

Answer (score 0):

As we have added last month cost in this month however, cost is exceeding so, please provide approval for the attached cost.

Please find enclosed!

Comment: The wording you suggest that the poster use is flawed in several ways. Please consider revising the wording to make it more coherent.